# Managing Internal projects as if the manager was a client. Does this method have a name?

Tags: motivation, clients, management, customer-service

As a manager in a company, I found that some people within my team performs better when they are trusted with a task and when I manage them and the tasks I give them, like if I was a client. I debrief them, tell them what I want, give them deadlines, etc. then their mission is to come back to me with a project proposal, a breakdown of the deadline, deliveries, etc.

I was wondering if this type of management has a name? If the benefit of managing projects that way has been studied? Also if this has somehow been formalized by anybody (for example how do we organize follow up meetings with the team in charge of project, deliveries, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a project management term for this that I'm aware of. This is generally referred to as a Delegation Management Style. It's considered a very good management technique and the sign of a skilled people manager.

It is very much like assigning a project as a client would and creates an environment for employees to excel and learn.